# URLResourceValue and setResourceValues Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurl, ios10, xcode8

I'm trying to figure out how i should proceed fox fixing below code using Swift 3.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray

for path in paths {
    let dir = path as! String
    print("the paths are \(path)")
    let urlToExclude = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: dir)
    do {

        try urlToExclude.setResourceValue(NSNumber(value: true), forKey: URLResourceKey.isExcludedFromBackupKey)

    } catch { print("failed to set resource value") }
}
```

The error that i'm getting is [image: this]

I used the above code for excluding files from backing up to the iCloud and it used to work fine for previous version of Swift but after updating to Xcode 8 I'm just stuck.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: `urlToExclude` is type of `URL` you might want to cast it to `NSURL`:
`let urlToExclude = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: dir) as NSURL`

Comment: @SiavashAlp that worked too but shouldn't Xcode's suggestion be taken care of ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Xcode suggestion "Use struct URLResourceValues and URL.setResourceValues(_:) instead" is prompting you to write something like this:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

for dir in paths {
    print("the paths are \(dir)")
    var urlToExclude = URL(fileURLWithPath: dir)
    do {

        var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
        resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
        try urlToExclude.setResourceValues(resourceValues)

    } catch { print("failed to set resource value") }
}
```

Please try.

**NOTE**

Please note that the file URL has to be a var - if it's a let you will get strange error messages (see comments).

Comment: Perfect! Looks like it resolved all the errors and taken care of all the Xcode's suggestions. Gonna run tests on my app now.

Comment: Also i just had to add this: var urlToExclude = URL(fileURLWithPath: dir as! String)

Comment: @Dushyant, you may be missing I removed `as NSArray` from the first line.

Comment: Yes, I was. Thank You!

Comment: This does not work for me in the released Xcode 8. It wants a [URLResourceKey : AnyObject], but the docs say it should take a [URLResourceKey : Any]. The Xcode-generated interface file shows it taking a URLResourceValues. But the compiler doesn't want that.

Comment: @Rick, my code above is tested in the released version of Xcode 8. I have experienced such odd behaviour a few times, but cannot reproduce the same issue now. Please try to create a minimum project which can reproduce your issue, and if you cannot fix your issue by yourself, start a new thread with showing whole code of the minimized project. Please do not forget to declare that your issue is not the same as this thread.

Comment: @Rick I'm having the same exact issue as you here. Xcode 8 and swift 3 are a serious headache.

Comment: I found my problem. The URL I was setting the values on was a "let," not a "var," and so the Swift compiler gave me a series of very confusing error messages (depending on what I tried).

Answer (score 11):

Additionally to what [TheEye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630732/5376091) provided, make sure your URL is a var and not a let.

That is what made my code work after migrating to swift 3.

Comment: Ok, I lost 2 hours because of this. It now works, after setting it as a var... can you explain why it needs to be so?

Comment: Ah, found my own answer to that... Since Swift 3 URL is a struct, therefore you cannot call mutating methods on the immutable value that is returned from the getter. To modify the URL first assign it to a var.